# Attach onDomContentLoaded function call to DOM object in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, ag-grid

```
<div id = "myGrid" onDomContentLoaded = "console.log('this')"></div>
```

Is there a way to attach javascript logic like this that runs after all defered scripts have been run, and that maintains the dom element as 'this'?

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered on the `document`.  It will not be available on children of the document.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Is there anything that will be available on the children?

Comment: Also, if you want to wait until all the defered scripts are finished, you should use the `load` event instead.  `DOMContentLoaded` only means the document has been parsed into the dom.

Comment: Why must the event handler be on the children?  What about processing the event on the document, and then running a callback that puts output in the child, will not work for you?

Comment: I could instead use an event that asks the dom for all myGrid objects after they are loaded, i just throught it would be nice to not have to do that.  Because in the future I may have many different types of objects, some existing more than once in a page, and it seems easier to call the constructor inside the html tag.

Comment: The DOM can only have one `myGrid` as your markup currently is presented, as it is an id.  Ids are expected to be unique.  So if you are repeating that id in your document, you are generating invalid markup.

Comment: Fair enough, I will change it to class = "myGrid" and use the querySelectorAll.

Comment: in addition to everything noted above, `console.log('this')` will log the literal string `'this'` - you need to remove the quotes to use the value of the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write it like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: I was seeking a way to bind 'this' to the HTML DOM element that would house my grid.  In your case, I would be binding this to the window object.